# why I change the navigator props execute twice handler?

Tags: react-native

here is my View to switch page

```
this.props.navigator.push({
  component: QuestionDetail,
  passProps: {
    id: id,
    enteredDetail: function() {
      console.log(this)
    }
  }
});

// in QuestionDetail
render: function() {
  this.props.enteredDetail();
....
```

in Xcode I saw this

```
RCTJSLog> {"navigator":{},"route":{"passProps":{"id":"1010000002652090"}},"id":"1010000002652090"}
RCTJSLog> {"navigator":{},"route":{"passProps":{"id":"1010000002652090"}},"id":"1010000002652090"}
```

it appear twice! why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/151

> in order for the react diffing algorithm to correctly reset properties
>   back to their default state, we create a single dummy "defaultView"
>   for every type of view